# How can I get my discord bot to DM a member and myself?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py, dm

How, if possible, would I get my discord bot (in python) to DM another user and whoever sent the command (telling them what they said)?

Edit: Solved, thanks Patrick Haugh - https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh
btw here's my code i have in case anyone else has the same problem:

```py
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    if message == None:
        await ctx.send('You need to put a message')
    else:
        await user.send(message)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send('DM Sent')
        await ctx.author.send('"' + message + '"' + ' sent to ' + str(user))
        # just so i can see every dm (a bit creepy ik but hey it's my bot so i'll do it)
        print('"' + message + '"' + ' sent to ' + str(user))
```

Comment: If you're trying to get the two users in a private chat with the bot, I'm pretty sure that Discord doesn't allow that.  The documentation for [`ClientUser.create_group`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.create_group) says that bot accounts can't use it.

Comment: nah, i want it to dm a user, then dm the person who used the command telling them what they said, im trash at explaining thing so i'll just say the steps i want it to do
**1. person types command '.dm @user 'message' 2. bot dms user 3. bot clears persons text 4. bot says in chat 'DM Sent' 5. bot dms person saying what they wanted to get dmed**
       rn i only have steps 1-4

Comment: my current code is

`@client.command()
`async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):`
        `if message == None:`
                `await ctx.send('You need to put a message')`
        `else:`
                `await user.send(message)`
                `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)`
                `await ctx.send('DM Sent')`

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet should answer your question:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    await message.author.send("Content")
    await client.get_user(other_user_id).send("Content")
```